# Ping: Result shows 56(84) instead of what is expected

Tags: bash, shell-script, ping

I'm trying to modify a script to show lost packets as well as ping results. I'm only including the section that isn't working as some of the commands in the script are company specific.

```
for myHost in $HOSTS; do
   PINGFULL=$(ping -f -c 1000 "$myHost")
   PINGLOSS=$(echo $PINGFULL | grep loss | cut -d ',' -f 3 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,4}')
   PINGVAL=$(echo $PINGFULL | head -n 5 | tail -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 4)
   echo "$PINGVAL"
   echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S") / $myHost / $PINGVAL / $PINGLOSS" 
done
```

Expected result is

```
2015-05-06_19:00:21 / 192.168.20.102 / 0.157/0.329/0.410/0.023 / 0
```

What I'm getting though is

```
2015-05-06_18:43:11 / 192.168.1.101 / 56(84) / 0
```

$PINGVAL is what is messing up.

I have tried using head/tail and grep to get the specific line, and when I run the line at the cli, it works and shows me just the 3rd set, but when I run it together in the script, errors.

I'm wondering if I should put it into a second while in the script.

Edit: I thought I should add, the script works the orginal way (without the packet loss result).

Original:

```
for myHost in $HOSTS; do
   PING=$(ping -f -c 1000 "$myHost" |grep 'rtt' | awk '{print $4}')
   echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S") / $myHost / $PING" >> "$LOGFILE" 2>&1
  done
```

Comment: You have at least two problems: 1) you need quotes around `$PINGFULL`, 2) the 5th line of `ping -c 1000` doesn't contain the `rtt min/avg/max/mdev` line -- try `tail -1` without the `head -n 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without double quotes around `$PINGFULL`, it's turning multiple lines into a single line, so you're getting the first line.

Also, the rtt stats are on the last line, so get rid of the `head -n 5`.

```
for myHost in $HOSTS; do
   PINGFULL=$(ping -c 5 "$myHost")
   PINGLOSS=$(echo "$PINGFULL" | grep loss | cut -d ',' -f 3 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,4}')
   PINGVAL=$(echo "$PINGFULL" | tail -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 4)
   echo "$PINGVAL"
   echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S") / $myHost / $PINGVAL / $PINGLOSS" 
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I was getting pretty braindead last night or I likely would of spotted the quotes missing.